# -bash express: command not found

Tags: javascript, bash, express, npm

I am getting a very odd error trying to install the express-generator with and without `sudo`.

I need to run: `npm install express-generator -g` and then `express --ejs name_here` but when executing the first command, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express-generator" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/LICENSE' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/[name]/Documents/Projects/MEAN Stack Tutorial/npm-debug.log
```

After trying `sudo npm install express-generator -g` I get this:

```
/Users/[name]/.npm/bin/express -> /Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.1 /Users/[name]/.npm/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
```

Then running `express --ejs name_here` returns `-bash: express: command not found`

Is there a way I can solve this issue? The other questions on SO seem to have fixed the issue by trying sudo but not for me.

Comment: What returns ```sudo express --ejs name_here``` after ```sudo npm install express-generator -g```?

Comment: `sudo: express: command not found`

Comment: try to use a full path: ```/Users/[name]/.npm/bin/express``` or ```sudo /Users/[name]/.npm/bin/express```

Comment: do a full answer, you are correct, it worked! But what could be the possible reason for it not working without sudo?

Comment: Done. Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an `express` command with a full path: `/Users/[name]/.npm/bin/express` or `sudo /Users/[name]/.npm/bin/express`.

Looks like `PATH` variable wasn't set after installation. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))